# Why is Capybara unable to see the contents of this page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to write an Rspec request spec using Capybara. It seems that everything is working correctly **except** that Capybara sees the page as blank.

Good signs:

- The page loads fine in a browser
- Tailing the log shows that the correct view is rendered during the test run
- Any logging statements I put in the views are executed
- If I use `assert_select "h1", :text => "hello world"`, the test passes.

Bad signs:

- If I use `page.should have_content('hello world')`, it fails, saying `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "/html"`
- If I do `$stdout.puts page.html`, it's empty except for a doctype

My test looks something like this:

```
describe "working with foos" do
  it "should have a 'new foo' form" do
    get '/foos/new'
    assert_select 'h1', text: 'hello world' # passes
    page.should have_content('hello world') # fails
    $stdout.puts page.html                  # empty except for a doctype
  end
end
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 7):

## The forehead-slapping answer

... which I'm sharing to save others the same pain.

Capybara uses the `visit` method to set up its page variable.

```
visit '/assembly/manage/task_lists/new'
```

Don't use `get` with Capybara:

```
get '/assembly/manage/task_lists/new'
```